# creating user id's (best route)

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for the best way to write out a php/mysql query to create unique user id's rather than using the autoincrement method in mysql.

Ex: Facebook gives users a long string of numbers as a user id when singing up before you can assign a username.  This string of numbers can be used to view your profile OR you can use username.  I want users to be able to change username in the future, so don't want to design my system based on username.

I don't know how big the site will get, so please take that into consideration with the solution.  I don't want something that is going to be server intensive if there are alot of users signing up.

Comment: Whats wrong with autoincrement?

Comment: Well I don't want the number starting at 1 (I want a longer string of numbers for the user id)...is it possible to start at a higher number for AI?

Comment: @kdjernigan You can set the `increment` value higher for a MySQL table by *altering* that table: `ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 12345;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a *best route* for something like this. Essentially you need to ask yourself what your system requires. You may be able to use an email address as the ID, an auto-incremented number, MD5 hash, or even a heavy-entropy GUID.

Keep in mind that email addresses may change, auto-incremented numbers can be leveraged in automated exploits, and there's technically some chance of hashes colliding.

If you decided to go the route of generating a high-entropy GUID using PHP, you could do so using a function like [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

```php
echo uniqid(); // 513ac40699d85
echo uniqid("_", true); // _513ac3e00bfe46.78760239
```

The second line shows the two arguments you can provide; a prefix, and a request for more entropy, which will result in a more unique result.

Comment: I like this method.  Is there a way to avoid special characters when creating a uniqid (for example in your second example it included an underscore and a period?

Comment: @kdjernigan The `_` was the result of me explicitly requesting it. The `.` is the result of high-entropy. Note the first line results in neither of these characters.

Comment: is this a better route than what was suggested by: VR17? Both seem like decent ideas to use.

Comment: @kdjernigan Well, `uniqid` generates a unique number immediately, without requiring you to make two trips to the database, grab bits and pieces of values, stitch them together, and re-insert into tables. So, I personally would prefer the shorter, simpler route :)

Answer (score 1):

You should follow some algorithm like this:

1. Enter your new user into the database.
2. Get the record ID
3. Generate the userID
4. Insert the userID next to the name into the sql database.

**Enter your new user into the database.**

```
//get username from previous form
$user=$_POST['user'];
// login into mysql server and prepare data for writing
$connect=mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $pass);
$selectdb = mysql_select_db('mydb');
$query = "insert into users_table set
username='$user';";
$run_query=mysql_query($query);
```

**Get the record ID**

```
$id=mysql_insert_id();
```

**Generate the userID**

```
$first_chars=substr($user, 2);
$year=date('y');
$new_user_id= $first_chars.$year.$id;
```

**Insert the UserID next to the name into the sql database**

```
$query="update users_table set userid='$new_user_id' where id='$id';";
$run_query=mysql_query($query);
if (!$run_query) {
   echo mysql_error();
}
else {
   echo 'your user name is '.$user.' and user id is '.$new_user_id ; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql as a database. Wampserver combines everything and makes it easy. However, i'm not sure if I can help you very much because your question is very vague. Add some more detail please.

Comment: I rewrote the question.  I meant the best way to write a php/mysql query to create the actual ID for the user (similar to facbeook how each user in given a long string of numbers as an ID before assigning a username)

Comment: Are you hosting the site or are you paying someone else to? And if you're paying do you have access to FTP server?

Comment: I own a hosting company so I own the servers the website is on..needless to say yes I have FTP access.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hexdigest like sha or md5 to generate an id something like `sha1($uname+$timestamp+$salt)`

By doing this your will be storing a lot of data for each entry as sha1 takes up 40 bytes.You have already mentioned that the site is may go big,making it a huge amount of data.Decide whether its worth that lot of space.

PS:you can always slice the string,but the collision chance is more that way.